# cast activity to interface leads to errors "Cannot cast..."

Tags: android, interface, android-activity

I would like to know how it is possible to send a reference of the first activity 'MainActivity' when we call a class OtherClass from the second activity. MainActivity called SecondActivity with an Intent, and SecondActivity has to send a reference of MainActivity to Otherclass, so that OtherClass sends the final result to MainActivity, like this :

```
public class ActA extends Activity implements OtherClass.MyInterface {
    //...
    //actA sends Intent to actB
}


public class ActB extends Activity {
    //send interface actA to otherClass 
    ActB actB = new otherClass( (OtherClass.MyInterface)ActA.class );//wrong: cannot cast from Class<ActA> to myInterface

    //or : actB = new ActB(arg1, ActA.class);//wrong: ask me to change the constructor of Otherclass



//constructor of otherclass
public OtherClass( OtherClass.MyInterface resultReceiver)

//in OtherClass 
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myFunc();
}
```

Would you know how to fix these errors?

Comment: you should not pass direct instance to other activity. there are other methods for that. what is your purpose

Comment: what are you trying to do here. Why do you need reference of activityA in ActivityB??

Comment: Don't do this, it's a way to create huge memory leaks.

Comment: It was not very clear in my explanation, sorry. OtherClass needs to send the final result to MainActivity (I edited my post), I could try with a broadcast caught by MainActivity, but the code was made by someone else, and allow to add a parameter with the interface Type. Which is MainActivity in my case, but it does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Iam not yet clear completely. This is a Ugly solution but it will answer your question

But i guess your need from your question as
`What you need is to set a listener that will get called when you process something asynchronously`

Simply

keep a seperate class as singleton

Example:

```
public class singletonClass{

private yourInterface myInterface;
private singletonClass instance;

// Use this method to get the object of this class
public static singletonClass getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new singletonClass();
    return instance;
}

public yourInterface getListener()
{
    return myInterface;
}

public void setListener(yourInterface listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}

}
```

Now from your `ActivityA`

```
singletonClass instance = singletonClass.getInstance();
instance.setListener(this);
```

Make sure that your `ActivityA` `implements` the interface

Then from `ActivityB`

```
singletonClass instance = singletonClass.getInstance();
yourInterface listener = instance.getListener();
```

Then call the Constructor using the `listener` above

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post above, it was not very clear I guess, sorry about that : OtherClass needs to send the final result to MainActivity (I edited my post), I could try with a broadcast caught by MainActivity, but the code was made by someone else, and allow to add a parameter with the interface type. Or is there a way to retrieve the activity that was used to send the intent between MainActivity and SecondActivity? Something like getIntent().getActivity()?

Comment: OK, I used a broadcast, I did not find out what was wrong with the cast, I will put this as an answer thanks for your help